# LXML builder for XML file

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, args, keyword-argument

EDITED AGAIN:

I'm trying to reproduce the a file that has the general format of the following:

```
1. <things>
2.  <parameters>
3.    <parameter1 p_variable1="" />
4.    <parameterN p_variableN="" />
5.  </parameters>
6.  <thing t_variable1="" t_variableN="">
7.    <nodes>
8.     <node_1 n_variable1=""/>
9.     <node_N n_variableN=""/>
10.   </node>
11.   <edges>
12.     <edge_1 e_variable1=""/>
13.     <edge_N e_variableN=""/>
14.   </edges>
15. </thing>
16. <comments>
17.    <comment_1 c_variable1=""/>
18.    <comment_N c_variableN=""/>
19.  </comments>
20.</things>
```

I coded this:

```
from pprint import pprint
from lxml import etree
import lxml.etree as ET
from lxml.builder import E
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

#node attributes
id_n = "1"

#edge attributes
source = "1"
target = "2"

#comment attributes
node_comment = "1"
content_comment = "putative"

root=etree.Element("things")
parameters=etree.SubElement(root, "parameters")
thing=etree.SubElement(root, "thing")
comments=etree.SubElement(root, "comments")
nodes=etree.SubElement(thing, "nodes")
edges=etree.SubElement(thing, "edges")
node=etree.SubElement(nodes, "node", id='%s' %id_n)
edge=etree.SubElement(edges, "edge", source='%s' %source, target='%s' %target)
comment=etree.SubElement(comments, "comment", node='%s' %node_comment, content='%s' %content_comment)

#writes the new nodes and comments to a XML file
newfile = (etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8'))
print newfile
```

And I got this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<things>
  <parameters/>
  <thing>
    <nodes>
      <node id="1"/>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
      <edge source="1" target="2"/>
    </edges>
  </thing>
  <comments>
    <comment content="OFF_CBa contacts AIIe" node="1"/>
  </comments>
</things>
```

So, everything seems to work, save the fact that I can't figure out how to get variables into the "thing" line (line 6). Defining the subclass "thing" as:

```
thing=etree.SubElement(root, "thing", v1='%s' %v1_a)
```

in which v1_a is a string variable always gives an error, either "keyword can't be an expression" or "incomplete format" or just "invalid syntax."

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "classes and subclasses"? There is no complete code that can be tested, only disconnected snippets.

Comment: @ mzjn I'm sorry for being unclear. I'm trying to get this:
<things>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <thing v1="">
        <nodes>
        </nodes>
        <edges>
        </edges>
    </thing>
    <comments>
    </comments>
</things>
Defining the subclass "thing" as 

thing=etree.SubElement(things, "thing", v1='%s' %v1_a)

in which v1_a is a string variable always gives an error, either "keyword can't be an expression" or "incomplete format" or just "invalid syntax." But, this is exactly the same way I put variables into "node" and "edge" and "comment."

Comment: The previous comment should be in the question. And please provide complete code that can be copy-pasted to demonstrate the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: edited. thanks @mzjn

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to improve the question, but you still have not provided **complete code** that reproduces the error. I'm sorry for harping on about this, but instead of saying "the string variables referenced by %s are defined earlier", why not simply include variables with values in the code in the question?

Comment: @mzjn: Edited again, thanks.

Comment: Replacing `thing=etree.SubElement(root, "thing")` with `thing=etree.SubElement(root, "thing", v1='%s' %v1_a)` (plus a value for `v1_a`) works fine for me. There is no error. I don't see what the problem is.